# viewing svg sprites with xslt

Tags: xslt, svg

My team's designer has us using SVG "sprites" in our application. I'm want to be able to see all the available images. I was going to parse the XML and build something on the back end but then I thought about XSLT. I'd like to have an XSLT file that parses the SVG and creates a list of images. I'm close to getting it... here's what I have.

Sample SVG (although I also tried the sample file in the post):

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/pages/sprites.xslt" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="fitness" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(5 3)" stroke-linecap="square">
        <path d="M5.8,27.0664159 L5.8,10.6333223 C5.8,4.7607008 10.5607008,0 16.4333223,0 L16.4333445,0 C22.3059668,0 27.0666667,4.7607008 27.0666667,10.6333223 L27.0666667,47.3666778 C27.0666667,53.2393002 31.8273665,58 37.699989,58 L37.7000111,58 C43.5726335,58 48.3333333,53.2393002 48.3333333,47.3666777 L48.3333333,30.9333333"/>
        <polygon points="11.6 50.267 11.6 47.367 9.667 44.467 9.667 32.867 11.6 29.967 11.6 27.067 0 27.067 0 29.967 1.933 32.867 1.933 44.467 0 47.367 0 50.267"/>
        <polygon points="54.133 30.933 54.133 28.033 52.2 25.134 52.2 13.533 54.133 10.633 54.133 7.733 42.533 7.733 42.533 10.633 44.467 13.533 44.467 25.134 42.533 28.033 42.533 30.933"/>
      </g>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

and the XSLT file found here:

[How can I show all symbols in an SVG file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651402/how-can-i-show-all-symbols-in-an-svg-file)

It mostly works... it creates all the dom objects I'm expecting out of the box, which is pretty amazing. But inside `use` I get:

```
#shadow-root (closed)
```

which is what we see in our actual app... but in our app, the image is nested inside the shadow-root. But in this version, it's empty. Seems basically the same as how we're doing it on the app side. What's the issue?

Comment: If all your icons are like the one shown, they have neither stroke nor fill color. Try to group your `<use>` elements with a `<g fill="black" stroke="black">`. But you'll have to ask your designer if that would give the desired result.

Comment: That's true, and I was going to add a style to fix that. (We use CSS to change the sprite colors.) But the SVG isn't being put into the shadow-root... so I need to get that working first. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the symbols from a file, write them into the output and reference locally.

Aditionally, you need to define a size for the used elements (the default would be 100%). As `position()` is one-based, subtract one to start top-left with the display.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <svg>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//svg:defs"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <g stroke="black" fill="black">
        <xsl:for-each select="//svg:symbol">
          <use width="32" height="32">
            <xsl:attribute name="x"><xsl:value-of select="(position()-1) mod 10 * 32"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="y"><xsl:value-of select="floor((position()-1) div 10) * 32"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">#<xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
          </use>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```