# Automatically put many SVGs into single PDF, each on a single page

Tags: svg, npm, latex, pdf-generation

I want to make available about 2000 graphics [(emojis) for Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358468/41085) users. They are all in individual SVG files (about 1–10 KByte) with square aspect ratio originally, but there is also an automatically generated *spritesheet* containing them all as `<symbol>`s. Since the sheer number exceeds some limits (e. g. Github preview is limited to 1000) and the small file size wastes a lot of space on file systems with large block size and also potentially requires a lot of network requests (e. g. HTTP 1.x), I consider putting them into a single PDF file as individual pages. The respective Latex packages support adding specific pages from PDFs as graphics, but I have not found a way (yet) to utilize SVG *symbols*. Therefore, I currently prefer the PDF solution. However, while I know how to convert a single SVG to a single-page PDF, e. g. using Inkscape, I am not sure which programs to use to create a small, fast and portable (e. g. npm-based) script to make a single multi-page PDF out of either hundreds of SVG files or of a single SVG spritesheet. Any advice? Ideally, the 4+ hexadecimal digits that the SVG file names consist of would be used to sort and perhaps label the PDF pages.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you consider fast, but if you want an automatic conversion from svg to something latex can include, have a look at the `svg` package.

Comment: For the "one image per page" requirement, it might be worth looking at the `standalone` document class. For example in its tikz mode, it puts one `tikzpicture` per page, something similar might be doable for svg as well

Answer (score 1):

This is inspired by [an approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105272/viewing-svg-sprites-with-xslt/47106164#47106164) I used in another answer. To make the `<symbol>`s render visibly, you could use a XSLT transformation, placing each icon in a separate `<svg>` container on a HTML page. Then distribute them out onto separate pages with a CSS `@media print` rule. That way you could open the file in a browser and print it to pdf from there.

First, you would be adding this line to the begining of your spritesheet:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sprites_paged.xslt" ?>
```

The referenced `sprites_paged.xslt` would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
        <style>
svg { display: none; }
/* icon sizes to your liking */
.icon { display: block; width: 1in; height: 1in; }
@media print {
  .icon { break-after: page; }
}
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="//svg:svg"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="//svg:symbol">
          <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <xsl:attribute name="viewBox"><xsl:value-of select="@viewBox"/></xsl:attribute>
            <use>
              <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">#<xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
            </use>
          </svg>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```